# error about using c++ macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++

code like this, I run a c++ project source code in Visual Studio 2015,

### this is a c++ project using a lot of mfc.

```
#define STR(s) #s
#define XSTR(s) STR(s)
#define CP_VERSION_M 6
#define CP_VERSION_MI 1
#define CP_VERSION_RE 2
const char *cpVersionString = XSTR(CP_VERSION_M)"."XSTR(CP_VERSION_MI)"."XSTR(CP_VERSION_RE);
```

---

this can cause a syntax error, but I don't know why ?
and  A"."B"."C ,  what "." means? what is the value of *cpVersionString?
Can you help me ... thx.

the error means Not found  the text  operator of the user defines.

Comment: `cpVersionString` points to the character literal `"6.1.2"`

Comment: This code has nothing in common with MFC

Comment: why dont you just print it to see what is its value? (e.g. `std::cout  << cpVersionString << std::endl;`)

Comment: If you search for user-defined literals, which I assume is mentioned in the error (but I can't know because you paraphrased it), then you will find a page like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) and notice a common theme of `"str"something`, which is in your code here.

Comment: I'd define this version string as `CString sVersion; sVersion.Format(_T("%u.%u.%u"), CP_VERSION_M, CP_VERSION_MI, CP_VERSION_RE);`

Comment: Looks like a typo. `STR` instead of `XSTR`?

Comment: I don't quite understand the part `what "." means?` This is your coude, isn't it. -- To improve readability I suggest to add spaces between the `` XSTR macros and the `"."`, the compiler separates the tokens anyway.

Comment: @harper, It does actually make a difference whether there is a space between them or not since C++11, and this feature is supported by VS2015. This is one of a few breaking changes.